# Collect and print title of events from webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get my program to collect and print the title of events from a website. The problem with my code is that it prints more than the title of the event. It provides the hyperlink as well. How to I get rid of the hyperlink?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_toscrape = "https://www.ntu.edu.sg/events/Pages/default.aspx"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_toscrape)
info_type = response.info()
responseData = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(responseData, 'lxml')

events_absAll = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title_first"})
for events in events_absAll:
    if len(events.text) > 0:
        print(events.text.strip())
print(events_absAll)
```

Also, how do I get the for loop to keep repeating so that I can get the complete list of events such as the list below?

```
-​​7th ASEF Rectors' Conference and Students' Forum (ARC7)
-Be a Youth Corps Leader 
-NIE Visiting Artist Programme January 2019
- Exercise Classes for You: Healthy Campus@NTU
-[eLearning Course] Information & Media Literacy (From January 2019)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: remove this `print(events_absAll)` and it won't print the url.

Comment: and change this: `events_absAll = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title"})`

Comment: Only the first element has a different class, the rest all have one.

Comment: you may consider accepting an answer that helped you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comments:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_toscrape = "https://www.ntu.edu.sg/events/Pages/default.aspx"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_toscrape)
info_type = response.info()
responseData = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(responseData, 'lxml')

events_absFirst = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title_first"})
events_absAll = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title"})
for first in events_absFirst:
    print(first.text.strip())
for events in events_absAll:
        print(events.text.strip())
```

**OR (even better)**:

Using the class `ntu_event_detail` and finding the `a` inside it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.ntu.edu.sg/events/Pages/default.aspx")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

events_absAll = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_detail"})
for events in events_absAll:
    for a in events.find_all('a'):
        print(a.text.strip())
```

**OUTPUT**:
​​

```
7th ASEF Rectors' Conference and Students' Forum (ARC7)
​Be a Youth Corps Leader
​NIE Visiting Artist Programme January 2019
​Exercise Classes for You: Healthy Campus@NTU
​[eLearning Course] Information & Media Literacy (From January 2019)
​[Workshop] Introduction to Zotero (Jan to Apr 2019)
​[Workshop] Introduction to Mendeley (Jan to Apr 2019)
​Sembcorp
Marine Green Wave Environmental Care Competition 2019 - Submit by 31 March 2019
​[Consultation] Consultation for EndNote-Mac Users (Jan to Apr 2019)
​The World Asian Business Case Competition, WACC 2019 at Seoul (proposal submission by 01 April 2019)
​Heartware Network
.
.
.
```

**EDIT**:
A better way would be to create a `list`, store the results in it, filter the empty strings (if any):

```
data =[]
for events in events_absAll:
    for a in events.find_all('a'):
        data.append(a.text)

filtered = list(filter(None, data))  # fastest
for elem in filtered: print(elem)
```

Comment: In your code you imported only `urlopen` and you are using it as  `response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_toscrape)`
I think it would be `response = urlopen(url_toscrape)`

Comment: @zxy, Indeed. I edited with a preferred way using `requests` instead. cheers

Comment: Thanks DirtyBit. I noticed the second set of code leave an extra space between each line compared to the first. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute = value selector with `^` (starts with) operator to target the beginning part of the class attribute of each title

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ntu.edu.sg/events/Pages/default.aspx'
response = requests.get(url)  
headers = {'User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
titles = [item.text.replace('\u200b','') for item in soup.select("[class^='ntu_event_summary_title']")]
print(titles)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for helping me out. I now have another issue. I am trying to collect the event date, time and venue. They came out successfully but then it is not reader friendly. How do I get the date, time and venue to appear separately like:

```
- event
Date:
Time:
Venue:
```

I was thinking of splitting but I ended up with lots of [] which made it looked even uglier. I thought of stripping but my regular expression but it does not appear to do anything. Any suggestions?

---

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url_toscrape = "https://www.ntu.edu.sg/events/Pages/default.aspx"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_toscrape)
info_type = response.info()
responseData = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(responseData, 'lxml')

events_absFirst = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title_first"})
date_absAll = tr.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_date"})
events_absAll = tr.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title"})

for first in events_absFirst:
    print('-',first.text.strip())
    print (' ',date)

for tr in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"ntu_event_detail"}):
    date_absAll = tr.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_date"})
    events_absAll = tr.find_all("div",{"class": "ntu_event_summary_title"})

    for events in events_absAll:
        events = events.text.strip()
    for date in date_absAll:
        date = date.text.strip('^Time.*')
    print ('-',events)
    print (' ',date)
```